# Sort NSArray with case sensitive comparator

Tags: ios, string, sorting, nsarray

It there any method or way to sort array of strings with sensitive comparator?

I mean if i have array of:

```
abbie
Ann
alice
Boris
Bob
billy
```

i need to receive:

```
Ann
abbie
alice
Bob
Boris
billy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

From the documentation:

> Returns an NSComparisonResult value that indicates the lexical
>   ordering of the receiver and a given string using a case-insensitive,
>   localized, comparison.

And the [Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Comment: I may be mistaken, but isn't the OP asking for a case-**sensitive** comparator?

Comment: @Jacky Boy according to ur comment the result will be: abbie, alice, billy, Ann, Bob, Boris     which is different from what i need

Comment: @qegal  no, there is no such comparator provided :(